# What is the canonical way to deal with CGo functions that expect size in memory in bytes?

Tags: opengl, go, cgo

I'm playing around with OpenGL and Go. It's mostly pretty intuitive, but there is a few awkward interface problems. The second argument of glBufferData should be the size of the buffer in memory.

```
C.glBufferData(C.GLenum(target), C.GLsizeiptr(size), ptr(data), C.GLenum(usage))
```

In the case that the buffer contains 32 bit floats each element will take of 4 bytes, so for the second argument I can do something like:

```
sizeofFloat := 4
size := sizeofFloat * len(buffer)
C.glBufferData(C.GLenum(target), C.GLsizeiptr(size), ptr(data), C.GLenum(usage))
```

Is there a better way to get the size of a type in memory other than just hard coding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unsafe.Sizeof` for that:

- http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe#Sizeof

This is the easiest since you're already using "unsafe" logic anyway. Otherwise, you might use `reflect.Type`'s `Size` method for that, to avoid importing unsafe:

- http://golang.org/pkg/reflect#Type